# Contradiction between the Law of Large Numbers and the Gambler's Fallacy?

Tags: probability

If I flip a fair coin 10 times, and all of them land on heads, according to the Law of Large Numbers I am more likely to get tails on the next flip. However, this is clearly the Gambler's Fallacy.

How am I misinterpreting the Law of Large Numbers?

Comment: Because it does not say what you think it says.  The Law of Large Numbers is a statement about limits, and as such it is unaffected by any initial finite pattern.

Comment: Are you saying that the law of large numbers says nothing about how fast the probabilities should approach the expected?

Comment: See [Does 10 heads in a row increase the chance of the next toss being a tail?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136870/does-10-heads-in-a-row-increase-the-chance-of-the-next-toss-being-a-tail) and this one adds some further intuition to that: [Statistics concept to explain why you're less likely to flip the same number of heads as tails, as the number of flips increases?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182488/statistics-concept-to-explain-why-youre-less-likely-to-flip-the-same-number-of). There are a number of other relevant questions on site.

Comment: The confusion is about joint probability of the sequence vs. conditional probability of the final toss. For independent events you have $p[x_{1:11}=H]=p[x_{1:10}=H]p[x_{11}=H]$. When making the final toss the history is known ($p[x_{1:10}=H]=1$), so there is only a *single* unknown toss ... and $n=1$ is certainly not a large number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry, this is a common misunderstanding. Let's consider this.

> If I flip a fair coin 10 times, and all of them land on heads,
>   **according to the Law of Large Numbers I am more likely to get tails on
>   the next flip**. However, this is clearly the Gambler's Fallacy.
>
> How am I misinterpreting the Law of Large Numbers?

The part I bolded is where the issue is, since the follow-up - that this is clearly the Gambler's Fallacy - is the correct angle.

The [Law of Large Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) states that

> the average of the results obtained from a large number of trials
>   should be close to the expected value, and will tend to become closer
>   as more trials are performed.

The first issue is kind of a footnote - that ten trials isn't near enough to qualify for the "large number." (How large the large number has to be depends on the distribution - in the case of the binomial coin toss, it's roughly 30.)

There is a deeper issue, though - even if you got the coin to land on heads *one million times in a row*, the odds of the next toss are still 50/50. How do we reconcile this?

The Law of Large Numbers' stock-in-trade is in *ratios*. Over huge numbers, the ratio of "interesting events::possible outcomes" approximates the probability of an interesting event happening on any single occasion. For a concrete example - it's actually plausible that you flip a coin one million times as heads more than tails in the long run, where your ratio is something like 100.1:100 million (heads:tails). The "Big Idea" here is that, when you run a huge number of trials, that large number in the denominator will dilute the freak ten-heads streaks that appear and otherwise substantial numbers (say, 1,000,000) on either side of the scale matter a lot less to the ratio between them.

(For further reading, Jordan Ellenberg does a fantastic job explaining this early in his book, *How Not to be Wrong*.)

Comment: Where did you get the info that 30 is a large number for binomial distributions?

Comment: Whoops - I was thinking Central Limit Theorem. Both that point and the actual answer (n = sigma/(epsilon*delta^2) for a probability delta of being off by more than epsilon) are found here: http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/36-220/lecture-10.pdf